# SQL--Regroup all the records based on their unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like following:

```
GroupID     ID      Name   Address   AAA   BBB  CCC    Other Columns
   1      00111     AAA     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   1      00122     BBB     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   1      00133     CCC     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   2      00144     DDD     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   2      00155     EEE     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   3      00111     AAA     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   3      00177     GGG     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   4      00188     PPP     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   4      00199     OOO     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   4      00177     GGG     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
```

So basically all the records have the same group ID are potential duplicate records. Records with the same ID may appear in different groups. I need to regroup them based on `ID`,and make them only appear once in the table.

If `ID'00111'`is in group 1 and group 3, the two groups' records have to regroup and have a unique GroupID. Note that in group 3, `ID '00177'` is in group 4 as well, so group 3 and 4 have to regroup.

So the result would be like the following:

```
GroupID     ID      Name   Address   AAA   BBB  CCC    Other Columns
 1+3+4    00111     AAA     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
 1+3+4    00122     BBB     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
 1+3+4    00133     CCC     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
 1+3+4    00177     GGG     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
 1+3+4    00188     PPP     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
 1+3+4    00199     OOO     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   2      00144     DDD     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
   2      00155     EEE     -----    ---   ---  ---    ------------
```

It is challenging and this table has over 3 million records, but only 2 million unique IDs.
I am thinking to add one more column as the `Master Group ID` to flag records and merge them. But as the example provided, `'00111'` is in group 1 and 3 so group 1 and 3 has to combine, but in group 3 the other record `'00177'` appears in group 4, so group 1,3 and 4 have to combine. It seems like this big chain will never end.

Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood the question, but you can try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(GroupID) AS GroupID, ID, Name, Address, AAA, BBB, CCC, ...
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, Name, Address, AAA, BBB, CCC, ...
```

Continue the `SELECT` column list with the remainder of your columns.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but this only works for the duplicate records, it doesn't carry over the rest of the records within that group. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29d00/1

Comment: How should they be "carried over?"

Comment: sorry for not being clear.. as my example showed, i need 111,122,133,177,188 and 199 in a same unique group ID. :D

Comment: Hmm, because in group 2, neither of those two records has appeared in other groups. So they don't need to be regrouped whereas 'OOO',which is ID '00199', is in a group that has ID '00177' which appears in group 3 as well. So all the records in group 4 have to regroup with group 3 and 1. Does that make sense..?